# Reference request for gluing construction of lattices

Tags: reference-request, lattices

I would like to study gluing method of lattices (such as constructing Niemeier lattices from certain root lattices etc) and am looking for good references. I am aware of the book "Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups" but it is rather a collection of research papers and I cannot really follow it. I would appreciate it if someone kindly introduce me introductory books or survey papers on this subject.